# What are the income levels for korbanot?

Tags: korban

At what level of income/wealth would someone bringing an Olah be expected to bring

1. A bull?
2. A sheep or goat?
3. A pair of birds?
4. A mincha offering?

Similarly for a rising and falling sin offering, at what income level would you need to bring

1. A goat?
2. A pair of birds?
3. A mincha offering?

Edit: The answers in that question do not give actual figures.

Comment: These are very different questions. An Olah is a voluntary sacrifice and anyone can decide to bring anything they want. A "rising and falling sin offering" is obligatory and people must bring the appropriate category of item.

Comment: Also Nazir and metzora and yoledet